# Adding authoringRules in IIS doesn't set access

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to add a new rule in the system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules section of the applicationhost.config file for the $WebSite location using this line:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules IIS: -Location $WebSite -AtIndex 0 -name collection -value @{users="*";access="Read, Source";path="/"}
```

but surprisingly, the result is that only the users and path values are set in the config file:

```
<add users="*" path="/" />
```

I even tried changing the order of the hashtable values or defining different access values (only Read for instance) but the result is always the same.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the numerical value instead of the enum names solved my problem:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules IIS: -Location $WebSite -AtIndex 0 -name collection -value @{users="*";access=17;path="/"}
```

However, I would have thought that the String value would have worked since it does in most situations. If anyone finds a solution using the String value, I would appreciate it.

Edit:
I have played a little bit more with this piece of script and I finally found the right way of doing it. The problem was in fact that I was adding a space after the comma. So, rewriting the line this way, works:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules `
  -Location $webSite -name Collection `
  -value @{users="*";path="/";access="Read,Source"}
```

Comment: I know nothing about this but I wouldnt expect is to take the string since you are trying to pass 2 elements but the string is just one. Does `access="Read","Source";` work by chance. Shot in the dark.

Comment: No, this won't work since it tries to convert a System.Object[] variable to System.IConvertible. Also, having BitWise enum values comma-separated in a string is really the short way of doing it instead of -bor. Normally, the value should be casted but this is automatically done when passing parameters to a function where the parameters are typed.